# DeviseTokenAuth with multiple emails per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-token-auth

I want to allow my users to manage multiple email addresses, setting a primary one. I know Devise gem encourages the use of the gem devise-multi_email which I have used https://github.com/allenwq/devise-multi_email

The problem is that I also use devise-token-auth gem and it does not seem to play well with this. 
Adding the line `include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User` on my user breaks after I remove the email column on the `users` table in favor of the new `emails` table.

There does not seem to be much information on how to adapt this to work. I wish I could find a nice tutorial blog post about it.